# Cakephp edit.ctp not populating input boxes despite existing in $this->data

Tags: arrays, cakephp, edit

I'm struggling to find the answer to this. I have only been using CakePHP for a month and I've hit a problem. It's something I can fix by manually inserting the values but I expected my data to pre-populate. Here is what is happening:

The Model is Product which hasMany 'Dynamicprice'

I'm testing a product with the id of 7 (/products/edit/7).

the first part of my edit function is:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    $this->Product->id = $id;

    if (!$this->Product->exists()) {
        throw new NotFoundException('Invalid Product');
    }

    if ($this->request->is('get')){
        $this->request->data = $this->Product->read();
    }
    debug($this->request->data); 
    //other stuff setting vars for drop-down lists
}
```

the

```
debug($this->request->data);
```

gives me the following:

```
array(
'Product' => array(
'id' => '7',
'category_id' => '70',
'name' => 'Full Test',
'description' => 'This is to test all features',
'price' => '0.00',
'aesthetic' => true,
'image' => '',
'price_structure' => '2',
'suggest_for' => '',
'created' => '2012-06-28 12:49:06',
'modified' => '2012-06-28 12:49:06'
),
'Dynamicprice' => array(
  (int) 0 => array(
  'id' => '15',
  'product_id' => '7',
  'drop' => '600',
  'prices' => '6000:9.99, 12000:18.99 '
  ),
  (int) 1 => array(
  'id' => '16',
  'product_id' => '7',
  'drop' => '1200',
  'prices' => '6000:19.99, 12000:28.99 '
  ),
  (int) 2 => array(
  'id' => '17',
  'product_id' => '7',
  'drop' => '2400',
  'prices' => '6000:29.99, 12000:38.99 '
  )
)
)
```

However, whilst everything in ['Product'] pre-populates the ['Dynamicprice'] array does not pre-populate the following:

```
<?php
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.0.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.0.drop', array('label' => 'Drop 1 (mm). Enter "0" for "Any Drop"'));
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.0.prices', array('label' => 'Prices 1', 'type' => 'textarea', 'rel' => 'dynamic'));
?><hr><?php
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.1.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.1.drop', array('label' => 'Drop 2 (mm).'));
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.1.prices', array('label' => 'Prices 2', 'type' => 'textarea', 'rel' => 'dynamic'));
?><hr><?php
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.1.id');
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.2.drop', array('label' => 'Drop 3 (mm).'));
echo $this->Form->input('Dynamicprices.2.prices', array('label' => 'Prices 3', 'type' => 'textarea', 'rel' => 'dynamic'));
?>
```

Am I right to expect them to populate automatically and if so what have I done wrong?

I have created /Model/Dynamicprice.php with the following just to make sure:

```
   class Dynamicprice extends AppModel {
    public $name = 'Dynamicprice';
    public $belongsTo = 'Product';
```

But as I expected it didn't change anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the second time I've done this this week; ask a stupid question. Yes I was right to expect them to pre-populate. The problem is I got my naming conventions mixed up. "Dynamicprices.1.drop" shouldn't have the 's' at the end. Silly me!